# Find largest possible value of S(S=(min2∧min) )where min2 & min are smallest & next smallest integer in k elements of array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, min

There is programming problem on which I am working on. The problem is as:

Given an array A[] of N distinct elements. Let min2 and min be the smallest and the next smallest element in the interval [L,R] where 1 ≤ L < R ≤ N.

S=(min2 ∧min).

where ∧ is bitwise XOR operator.
I have to find the maximum possible value of S.

I have written 1 solution which finds the maximum possible value for S, but its complexity is high. I was thinking if it could be optimized in anyway. As even the range k of elements is not fixed, I have to calculate for all the ranges i.e. k = 2 to array's length.
The approach I am using is first taking k as 2 and starting from 0th element, finding min & min2 in first k elements, calculating S, if it is greater than the previous S, taking this as S, otherwise ignoring it. After this starting from 1st element I am finding min in next k elements & so on. Same with other higher ranges also i.e. 3,4,5... Following is the code I wrote:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num = 0, S = Integer.MIN_VALUE, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int[] input = null;

    try {
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = bufferRead.readLine();
        num = Integer.parseInt(s);
        s = bufferRead.readLine();
        String arr[] = s.split(" ");

        input = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i =0; i<arr.length;i++) {
            input[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    for(int k=2;k<=input.length;k++) {
         int j =0;

         while(j<input.length-k+1)
             {

             int i=j;

             for(i=j;i<(j+k);i++)
             {
             if(input[i] < min)
                 {
                 min2 = min;
                 min = input[i];
             }
                 else if(input[i] > min && input[i] < min2)
                 {
                 min2 = input[i];

             }


         }

         int st = (((min2 & min)^(min2 | min)) & (min2 ^ min));


         if(st > S)
             S = st;
            j++;
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         }

        }
        System.out.println( S );

    }

}
```

Can this be optmized somehow?

Comment: You can simplify S to just `a ^ b` (^ being xor here), that gives some more obvious structure to the problem

Comment: Thanks for pointing out harold!! Done

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with linear-time O(N) space algorithm.

To make things simpler, do it for the case where second smallest element comes after the smallest one. Then reverse the array and do it again (or just process the array backwards, starting from the last element).

Use every element of the array as rightmost element of interval (`A[R]`). Now the only element to be considered as leftmost element of interval (`A[L]`) is the nearest element smaller than `A[R]` if there is any. `A[L]`, `A[R]` are two smallest elements of this interval, so compute `S` for them and update the result if necessary. And the nearest smaller element could be found using a stack.

Pseudo-code:

```
result = -infinity
for each X in array A:
    while NOT stack.empty AND stack.top > X: stack.pop
    if NOT stack.empty:
        result = max(result, X XOR stack.top)
    stack.push(X)
reverse array A and repeat
```

Proof: This algorithm (exactly, its first half) tries every element of the array as second smallest element of some interval such that the (first) smallest element is to the left of it. Obviously this takes into consideration interval `A[L]..A[R]`. Also if we extend this interval to either side (or both) and all additional elements of this extended interval are greater than `A[R]`, then `A[R]` is still the second smallest element, and this interval is also considered by the algorithm (but it does not change the optimal value of `S`). If at least one additional element is smaller than `A[R]` or instead of extending, we start to shrink the interval, `A[R]` is not the second smallest element anymore, so such intervals are not considered on this particular iteration (but considered when we try some other element as the second largest one or when we expect the first largest element to the right of current element).

Comment: Can you explain this a bit as how does this covers all the subarrays?

Comment: An explanation added. Please tell me if anything is still unclear.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev May I ask how did you come up with this logic? Is it based on some fundamental algorithms of stacks or so? The solution here is really intuitive.

Comment: @BugshotGG: I don't remember this exactly, but the first thought about this problem was "what if we start with the second smallest element at every position?" Then it was obvious that this solves the problem if we could quickly find the (first) smallest element. And then I remembered the solution for this sub-problem using stacks. So I didn't start with stacks and didn't use anything "fundamental".